# display pdf in Iframe in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, pdf, iframe

Getting below error while displaying a pdf in iframe in lwc

```
top.location='https://utalmesivtakj--developer2.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/ex/errorduringprocessing.jsp'
```

My HTML :

```
<iframe id="pdfFrame" src={url} width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

JS :

```
get url(){
    return '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/FileDownload?file=069Db000002WFkfIAG/' ;}
```

Not able to understand issue?